# How to override the Checkbox widget class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Currently I have started to use Flutter.

How can I create a customized widget or override the Checkbox widget class?
The reason I want to do this is that I want to customize:

- checkbox
- splash color
- hover color
- focused
- pressed
- EnabledSelected
- DisabledSelected
- tick mark rendering

Comment: Either you can do with embedding them or copy the source and modify it there. The widgets aren't really designed to be extended.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: @GunterZöchbauer or someone, do you know why it is not recommended to extend widgets?

Comment: That's not really related to Flutter. Inheritance is just overused heavily. Inheritance is only for real `is-A` relationship, not for `does-a-bit-of-the-same` relationship. Usually if you think you need inheritance, you are likely wrong. Composition is much more powerful, especially in the long run.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I still didn't understand why not Inheritance, can you explain a bit more or provide some resources.  I have seen in some places the use of inheritance in the flutter gallery app given in flutter docs. 
https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/sliders (check custom slides code)

Answer (score 2):

**Flutter heavily favors composition over inheritance**, so extending the `Checkbox` is probably not the right way to do it.

Rather you should create a new `StatefulWidget`.
In the state's `build` method you would then either create a `Checkbox` with customized parameters or render something completely custom.
Because your list contains very custom stuff like changing the tick icon, you need to go with the latter.

That means you'll build a completely custom checkbox widget without relying on the existing one.
Exciting!

However, you probably don't want to start from scratch, so check out the [implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart) of the existing `Checkbox`.
It's okay to copy that code and then customize it to your needs.

One more thing: Once you're done, consider sharing your widget as a [Pub package](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages) to other Flutter programmers, freeing them from the burden if they want to the do the same.